# Custom user roles doesn't apply changes

Tags: php, user-roles

I have created a custom user role but something strange happens.

This is the role:

```
add_role('custom-role', 'Custom Role', array(
'activate_plugins' => false,
'delete_others_pages' => true,
'delete_others_posts' => false,
'delete_pages' => true,
'delete_posts' => false,
'delete_private_pages' => true,
'delete_private_posts' => false,
'delete_published_pages' => true,
'delete_published_posts' => false,
'edit_dashboard' => false,
'edit_others_pages' => false,
'edit_others_posts' => false,
'edit_pages' => true,
'edit_posts' => false,
'edit_private_pages' => true,
'edit_private_posts' => false,
'edit_published_pages' => true,
'edit_published_posts' => false,
'edit_theme_options' => false,
'export' => false,
'import' => false,
'list_users' => true,
'manage_categories' => false,
'manage_links' => false,
'manage_options' => false,
'moderate_comments' => false,
'promote_users' => false,
'publish_pages' => true,
'publish_posts' => false,
'read_private_pages' => false,
'read_private_posts' => false,
'read' => false,
'remove_users' => true,
'switch_themes' => false,
'upload_files' => true,
'update_core' => false,
'update_plugins' => false,
'update_themes' => false,
'install_plugins' => false,
'install_themes' => false,
'delete_themes' => false,
'delete_plugins' => false,
'edit_plugins' => false,
'edit_theme' => false,
'edit_files' => false,
'edit_users' => true,
'create_users' => true,
'delete_users' => true,
'unfiltered_html' => false
));
```

This is nothing fancy. But the problem is that at first I set all the values to `false`.
If I log a user in with the chosen role it shows `Dashboard`, `posts`, `reactions`, `profile` and `extra`.

The problem is that if I change a value from `false` to `true` nothing changes.
I have loged out and in,  removed my cookies and deleted my cache.

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: When and how are you using that code? Which capabilities are not working when you change them from `false` to `true`?

Comment: I use this in my `functions.php` and it doesn't matter what I change the only thing the users sees is: `Dashboard`, `posts`, `reactions`, `profile` and `extra`.

Comment: in WP doocumentation:
NB: This setting is saved to the database (in table wp_options, field wp_user_roles), so it might be better to run this on theme/plugin activation

It means that when you first run your code it is saved to db, and if you try to do it one more time it will not be changed becouse it is already in DB.. you should remove role before making changes..

Comment: Sorry but when I asked "when and how you use that code" I wanted to know if you use it on some action hook, if so, which one. Please, show us. It doesn't matter if you use it in functions.php or in a plugin (by the way, a plugin is really better place to manage user roles).

Comment: @Maikal. That was indeed the problem. Thnx

Comment: @cybmeta I just use it in my `functions.php`. No plugin or hook. It might not be the best way but it works for me!

Comment: That is not the correct way to add roles. As @Maikal said, roles must be added on plugin activation and removed on plugin deactivation.

Comment: @Maikal post your comment as an answer; future users will find the answer more easily.

Answer (score 0):

in WP documentation:

**NB: This setting is saved to the database (in table wp_options, field wp_user_roles), so it might be better to run this on theme/plugin activation**

It means that when you *first run* your code it is **saved to db**, and if you try to do it one more time it will not be changed becouse it is *already in DB*.. you should **remove role** before making changes..